# Get URL to a PDF thats not in documents directory - UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I have a PDF that is dynamically generated from saved core data every time, rather than stored in the documents directory as `NSData` `self.pdfData`,  rendered in a `UIWebView`.   Rather than using  `UIActivityController` to share the PDF i'd like to use `UIDocumentInteractionController` to get a full range of sharing options.  The issue is this only seems to be for saved PDF's in the documents directory.

```
NSURL *PDFUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sample" withExtension:@"pdf"];
```

Id rather not save it to documents directory then delete it, I was hoping for something more elegant.  I tried to get the URL directly from the `UIWebview` of the PDF using `self.webView.request.mainDocumentURL` however this returns `about:blank`

```
NSURL *PDFUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sample" withExtension:@"pdf"]; <----- 

    if (PDFUrl) {
        DebugLog(@"Loading document");

        self.documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:PDFUrl];
        [self.documentController setDelegate:self];
        [self.documentController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIDocumentInteractionController` only works with a file on the local file system. This means you must save the PDF to a file before you can use `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

Write the PDF data to a file in the caches folder (`NSCachesDirectory`), get its file URL, use the `UIDocumentInteractionController`, and then delete the file when complete.

Or use `UIActivityViewController` and pass the `NSData` of the PDF as the activity item.